# Firebase (client-side vs server-side)

Tags: python, django, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I'm building a PWA with django/python on the server-side and vue on the client-side and want to use firebase as a database as well as make use of the firebase authentication.

After some thorough research I realised that I had to make a few choices.

Question 1: Authentication

- I can do authentication on the client-side or server-side. Which one would be best (more secure) ?

Question 2: Database

- In terms of CRUDS I am a bit conflicted. Do I write all my data to firestore from the client-side?
- Do I rather use api's to communicate with my backend and then write data to firestore from the backend? What are the security implications of doing this?

Should I just use both in terms of context? If there are no security implications I would do my authentication client-side and my CRUDS from the server-side. I think I would also have to check authentication to write to the database from the backend.

Comment: Answer on your authentication question is below. Please create a separate post for the database question, as on Stack Overflow it is recommended to separate each question into a separate post. I also recommend picking a specific use-case in that new question. Firestore has client-side and server-side SDKs for valid reasons. Some use-case are better done in the client, others in a server. If there was a single "best" approach, it'd only provide a SDK for that approach.

Comment: Okay coolbeans. Thanks man - I only joined stack overflow about a week ago so I'm really not that in tune with the formalities yet.

Comment: There is a great Udemy course which I did on vue.js and firebase, might be useful https://www.udemy.com/build-web-apps-with-vuejs-firebase/learn/v4/content here everything is on the client-side, well almost everything

Comment: @WernerKotze wondering, did you ever ask the database question in another post? i have the same question.. (edit: nevermind found the answer [here](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Authentication of a user's credentials should always happen on a server, as it can't be securely done on the client's computer. What Firebase Authentication allows however, is that the authentication runs on Google's servers, while you control it from a simple client-side API call.

Comment: I understand this - but as far as I understand I can use the firebase admin SDK to also do user management on the server-side. Which is better?

Comment: The Admin SDK allows you to create user accounts, delete user accounts, update their profiles, etc. The client-side SDKs allow each user to do that themselves. You'll typically want to do most things client-side that can reasonably be done client-side.